# Does spring data jpa create new instance of EntityManager for each transaction?

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, spring-transactions

I can't find information about relationship between EntityManager and transactions in spring data jpa application.

Which one of the statements is correct:

1. new instance of EntityManager is created per transaction
2. one shared instance of EntityManager is used for all transactions

Comment: i assume by transaction you mean the use of @Transactional annotation?

Comment: Does it matter? @Transactional annotation is just one way of transaction management.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: *one shared instance of EntityManager is used for all transactions **in the same persistence context.***

We can have in consideration two things here:

First, the [definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) in the EntityManager Interface

> An EntityManager instance is associated with a persistence context. A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle are managed.
>
> The set of entities that can be managed by a given EntityManager instance is defined by a persistence unit. A persistence unit defines the set of all classes that are related or grouped by the application, and which must be colocated in their mapping to a single database.

Second, the constructor of the Spring SimpleJpaRepository:

```
public SimpleJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {


    Assert.notNull(entityInformation, "JpaEntityInformation must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(entityManager, "EntityManager must not be null!");


    this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
    this.em = entityManager;
    this.provider = PersistenceProvider.fromEntityManager(entityManager);
}
```

`em` is an attribute defined in that class with the `final` modifier:

```
private final EntityManager em;
```

And in the methods of the [SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/5ec2d41c446f0b6855b141af405e5f8552b5c539/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) are made calls to that `em` without create new instances of the EntityManager.

Comment: Not sure this is correct. Although EntityManager field in SimpleJpaRepository is final and SimpleJpaRepository doesn't create new instances of EntityManager, I see in debug mode that EntityManager is proxy. So creation of new instances of EntityManager can be hidden.